# Submit form data to servlet and retrieve answer without page reloading?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

On a webpage I want to submit form data with a POST request to a servlet, receive the answer and handle it according to the result. The page shall not reload. Unfortunately I'm not very experienced with this kind of things (HTML & JavaScript).

Currently I have managed to get two unsuccesful results:

1. Either the POST request is send (processed correctly by the servlet) and the page reloads and shows the plain XML result
2. Or the POST request is never send, the JavaScript functions does some processing but basically has no result.

I got the idea of doing it this way from this page: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp

Specifically:

> The XMLHttpRequest object is a developers dream, because you can: 
>   Update a web page without reloading the page

Currently I fail to do so.

---

I have an HTML form like this:

```
<form id="editform" 
    action="myAction" 
    method="post" 
    onSubmit="return submitForm(this);">

  ....

  <input type="hidden" name="operation" value="doSomething" />
  <input type="image" src="images/button.png" />
</form>
```

In the page's `head` section I have a JavaScript like this:

```
function submitForm(oFormElement)
{
  var xmlHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlHttpRequest.open (oFormElement.method, oFormElement.action, true);
  xmlHttpRequest.onload = function()
  { 
    if (xmlHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && xmlHttpRequest.status == 200) 
    {
      alert (xmlHttpRequest.responseXml);
    }
    else
    {
      alert ("Failed!");
    }
  };
  xmlHttpRequest.send (new FormData (oFormElement));
  return false;
}
```

If the JavaScript returns `false` then I don't see any POST request in the browser web-developer console and also the servlet never receives any request. The alert box prints *undefined* (case 2).

If the JavaScript returns `true` the POST request is indeed send and the correct result is returned but the page is reloaded (case 1).

Within the positive if-clause I want to handle the result XML and set the HTML elements accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `xmlHttpRequest.responseXml` `xmlHttpRequest.responseXML` must be used. Also it seems that `oFormElement.action` didn't pick up my `<input>` elements as I somehow hoped for...

Answer (score 0):

You should use jQuery **$.ajax**

Example:

```
$.ajax({
url: "myUrl", // url to make request
type: "POST", // method of request
data: {key: "value"}, // Here comes your data
success: function(response){ // If request is made successful
    //  Here you can handle response from your request
    console.log(response)
},
error: function(xhr){// If request has faced issue
    console.log(xhr.responseText)
}});
```

Comment: I don't really know how to work with jQuery but I put that code between the `<script>` tag - it seems not to work. The POST request is send but the page reloads.

Comment: I would prefer a solution without jQuery.

Comment: It doesn't work if you just copy and paste it inside script tags. This is a sample about how you can use it to make your request. You should insert $.ajax request inside a function and call it when your button is clicked.